# Given an integer $n$ find smallest integer $i$ such that $σ(i)=n$. Smallest Inverse Sum of Divisors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

Hi All I need some help I am trying to solve this problem which involves computation of sum of divisors and its inverse.

In other words Given an integer $n$ find smallest integer $i$ such that $σ(i)=n$

Explanation about my algorithm.
1 I am finding the sum of Divisor till $10^8$ and the computing its inverse in an hash table and answering each query in $O(1)$ for hast table, But I am getting TLE(Time limit exceeded) The expected running Time is 10s but My code is taking 11s can someone help me with some better approach or some hint how to do this within the given time limit Thanks.

problem link http://www.spoj.com/problems/INVDIV/

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 100000000
#define MAX1 100000000
using namespace std;
unsigned DIV[MAX];
unsigned INVDIV[MAX];
int main()
{

    int tc;unsigned c;
    for (unsigned i=1;i<=10000;i++)
    {
        c=i+1;DIV[i*i]+=i;
        for(int j=i*(i+1);j<MAX1;j+=i) 
        {
            DIV[j]+=i+c;
            c+=1;
        }

    }
    for(unsigned i=2;i<MAX;i++) 
    {
        if (DIV[i]<MAX)
         if (INVDIV[DIV[i]]==0) 
           {
            INVDIV[DIV[i]]=i;
           }
    }
    INVDIV[1]=1;
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&tc);
    while(tc--){
               scanf("%d",&n);
               if(INVDIV[n]!=0)printf("%d\n",INVDIV[n]);
               else printf("-1\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for us to tell you why it's timing out, or to help you see a better way to calculate it?

Comment: @Semiclassical No I am not asking why It is getting TLE, I am asking for help with some better approach. I posted my code here just to make clear that what I have done till now.Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you using that $\sigma$ is multiplicative anywhere in there? If $m,n$ are relatively prime, then $\sigma(mn)=\sigma(m)\sigma(n)$.

Comment: @Thomas No, Actually My algorithm is based on sieve method.

Comment: Do the spoj people want us discussing their questions here?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Spoj is not a live contest site it is an Archive of various problems so they don't have issue discussing problem with some one, There are many problems from Spoj has been discussed here.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10011/do-we-really-need-the-spoj-tag "Judging from the SPOJ forums, they do not seem upset about helpful hints and remarks being available on the internet (in fact, they set up a forum for that purpose). They seem upset, however, if workable source code is available on the internet."

Comment: @Lakshman, just a quick comment:  If $n > 1$, then $n = \sigma(i) \geq i + 1$, so that $i \leq n - 1$.  In general, determining an $i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sigma(i) = n$ might not be so easy, though I seem to recall a paper by Bach, Miller and Shallit to that effect.

Comment: @Lakshman, found the paper.  It's titled [Sums of Divisors, Perfect Numbers and Factoring](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0215083).

Comment: You might also find some interesting information in this [MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48564).